# AVRISP MKII does not appear in AVRStudio 4 (latest build 4.18 SP1)

Tags: avr

[image: AVRISP MKII Custom Enclosure]

I have a AVRISP MKII that I wish to program avr chips with through avrstudio 4 with.  However on the "select platform" the only think that resembles MKII is JTAGICE MKII which is not what I have?  Am I missing something here?  When I plug in the AVRISP MKII the drivers are all working and says it "sees" the device at least in windows.

Thanks,

Ril3y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmer selection in AVRStudio is user experience nightmare.

Are you going to Tools -> Program AVR -> Connect ?
And in the "Platform" list you should see "AVRISP mkII" as one of the options with "USB" as the only available port.

This should appear whether or not you have the programmer plugged in.  If you're missing it, it sounds like you may have an incomplete install of AVRStudio.  (I don't recall, but I think AVRStudio might install a USB driver or two during its install)

Answer (score 2):

The menu you are currently in is for selecting which emulator/simulator/debugger. AVRISP MKII doesn't support that, it's "only" a programmer. So simply pick whatever option in that menu, then later, pick the programmer in a different menu.